# Error while creating XML document in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I got this error while trying to create XML document from database data:

> error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Here's my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'db_test');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root></root>');

$currency = $xml->addChild('currency');
$currency->addAttribute('rate', '8');
$currency->addAttribute('code', 'PLZ');

$catalog = $xml->addChild('catalog');
$items = $xml->addChild('items');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `catalog`");
while($it = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $item = $items->addChild('item');
    $item->addAttribute('id', $it->id);
    $item->addAttribute('selling_type', "r");
    $item->addChild('name', $it->name.", ".$it->comment);
    $item->addChild('categoryId', $it->parent_id);
    $item->addChild('priceplz', $it->cost);    

    $r = $mysqli->query("SELECT `image` FROM `catalog_images` WHERE `catalog_id`='".$it->id."' AND `main`=1 LIMIT 1");
    if($i = $r->fetch_object()){
      $item->addChild('image', "/Media/images/catalog/big/".$i->image);
    }
    unset($r);
    unset($i);

    $item->addChild('barcode', $it->artikul);
    $item->addChild('description', $it->text);
    $item->addChild('available', "true");
    unset($item);
}
unset($result);
unset($it);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `catalog_tree`");
while($cat = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $category = $catalog->addChild('category', $cat->name);
    $category->addAttribute('id', $cat->id);
    if($cat->parent_id != 0) {
        $category->addAttribute('portal_id', $cat->id);
        $category->addAttribute('parentId', $cat->parent_id);
    }
    unset($category);
}
unset($result);
unset($cat);

$mysqli->close();

$xml->asXML('text.xml');

?>
```

If I'll comment the 'items' loop it works fine, otherwise it doesn't work...
Am I blind or what?

Comment: Check the generated XML (Use the source view in the browser). Here might be an error message or some unexpected output. Additionally this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37162005/2265374

Comment: @ThW many thanks! It's a shame th i didn't know about this function in browsers :(